# Error while reading excel file from Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to read excel file from pandas but I keep getting the below mentioned error. Any help ?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx",sheet_name="EPI")
print (df)
```

I am using Python 3 here but I also have Python 2 installed. While reading excel file in Python 2 I don't get any error.

[And I get the following error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjXLn.png)

Comment: Do you have Excel installed?

Comment: Yes excel is installed on my pc